# org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.10.4:push (code: 500, Internal Server Error)

Tags: java, maven, docker, archlinux

When trying to push a docker image, using

```
mvn deploy
```

I receive following exception:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.10.4:push (push) on project my_app: Error while pushing image 'd-docker.image' (code: 500, Internal Server Error)
```

my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <alias>docker.image</alias>
                        <name>d-docker.image:latest</name>
                        <build>
                            <from>d-rscript:latest</from>
                            <assemblyDescriptorRef>artifact</assemblyDescriptorRef>
                            <ports>
                                <port>8084</port>
                            </ports>
                            <command>java -jar /maven/${project.build.finalName}.jar</command>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The thing is, that pushing the docker image manually works perfect

```
docker push docker.image:latest
```

I don't know if it is important, but as OS I'm using Arch Linux.

can somebody give me a hint please?